# Laravel can not connect mariaDB on CentOs 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

[How to configure MariaDB in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650972/how-to-configure-mariadb-in-laravel-5)

The thread above mentioned that changing port 3306 to 3307,I tried it but still not work.

I write my code on local Windows,the port is also 3306, and the app can run, I copy the app to cloud host,OS is CentOs 7.2,the error appears.

And I am using Laravel `5.3` and mariaDB `10.2`.

The `.env` file is like this：

```
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

I can access it via terminal：

```
# mysql -uroot -p123456;
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

When running `php artisan migrate`，there is an error：

```
  [PDOException]                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What should I do？

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant part of `config/database.php`.

Comment: @Chris I have added the part of `config/database.php`.

Comment: This looks like your exact problem. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/setting-up-mariadb-with-laravel-5  Just so happens to be the first result on google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure MariaDB in Laravel 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650972/how-to-configure-mariadb-in-laravel-5)

Comment: What Database are you trying to connect to in `.env`? There should be something that says `DB_DATABASE` in there.

Comment: There may have been a specific reason for 3307.  Normally, the default of 3306 is 'correct'.

Answer (score 0):

check your `DB_PASSWORD` setting in `.env` file.

The error information says that `using password: NO` which meant no password used when connecting to db.