# Is there a MariaDB, Laravel 5.4 connector

Tags: mariadb, laravel-5.4

1. Is there a package I can download and load?
2. If not what would be the best way to connect MariaDB to Laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default MySql connection can be used to connect to MariaDB. You can see the following answer for clarification: [How to configure MariaDB in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650972/how-to-configure-mariadb-in-laravel-5)

However, it seems as simple as configuring the MySql connection as if it were MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks the link was helpful